# What is the default row terminator for a CSV (UTF-8) file exported from Excel?

Tags: java, excel, csv, formatting

I am attempting to write some code to, in short, turn a fixed-format file into a CSV file so that I can more easily read it into Azure's Data Factory.

But that's not the main point of this question, just the context. My question is really: what is the default line terminator that Excel uses for each row? I am attempting to print the contents of a CSV file (exported from an Excel sheet) that looks like this:

A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3

to an ArrayList (in Java.) I parse the file using Scanner, and I want to get all of the elements in an ArrayList, like so:

A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2 A3 B3 C3

Instead, however, when I run my code (which isn't worth showing as it's very simple and just calls Scanner.next() until the end is reached, adding each element to the ArrayList,) it returns:

A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3

What character or combination of characters is causing this? I tried checking whether each item was or contained a newline character before adding it to the list, but this had no effect on my output.

Answer (score 1):

CSV rows are seperated by line breaks.

You can use `Scanner#nextLine` in combination with `String#split` in order to get a line (representing a row) and get each cell of the row:

```java
try(Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("yourFile.csv"))){
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line=scan.nextLine();//a row
        String[] cells=line.split(",");//cells of a row
        //Process cells
    }
}
```

You could also use `BufferedReader`:

```java
try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile.csv"))){
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){//for each row
        String[] split=line.split(",");//all cells
        //Process cells
    }
}
```

---

**Notes**:

The code above uses the system default encoding. You can use a custom encoding like this:

```java
//Scanner
try(Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("yourFile.csv"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
    //...
}
//BufferedReader
try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("yourFile.csv"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
    //...
}
```

If you wish to use another encoding, you can just use that instead of `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Aside from this, CSV files often have a specific amount of cells per row. You might want to check this too.

If your CSV file has a header line, you can skip that by executing `scan.nextLine()` or `br.readLine()` before entering the loop.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. I'll give it a try tonight. The line-based method makes a lot more sense than what I was doing. Sorry I can't upvote you--I'm new around here so I don't even have enough reputation!